# Is it possible to create URL that redirect to external website with Hugo

Tags: hugo

Simply put, I want social URLs to my blog. For example, when going to `www.myWebsite.com/twitter`, the user gets redirected to `www.twitter.com/username`.

I'm also wondering if it's possible to generate them from the theme templates, that'd be neat!

Comment: Hugo does not support this. You need to modify the server settings to do this, i.e. Nginx or Apache. Similar discussion on the official hugo form: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/url-redirect-forwarding/4689/3

Answer (score 2):

Just put in a redirects section with a twitter.md file. The layout file for the redirect section should be placed in your layouts folder and look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={{ .Params.redirect_url }}">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

And the twitter.md file should be placed in your content folder and look like this:

```
---
title: Twitter
redirect_url: https://www.twitter.com/username
---
```

[Source on folder structure](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/directory-structure/)

Comment: Where do you place the the files exactly and is any other code or theme needed? Do you have an git link for a real example? Like ".redirect" is not a parameter in twitter.md right?

Comment: True... I updated the answer to accommodate your questions.

Comment: What is the name of the file with the HTML supposed to be? `./layouts/NAME?`

Comment: You can use your current layout and put an if statement around the meta refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo does not support that, but if it's hosted at Netlify you can get what you want using `_redirects`

Here is an example of `static/_redirects`:

```
/twitter                https://twitter.com/foo
/go/drive               https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BTwxZ85
/newsletter             https://complicatedUrlNoOnewillRemember/42FDEZ
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/) for details

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible with Hugo. There are already ready-made Hugo themes that realize something like this. For example, the following Hugo theme: https://github.com/gcc42/hugo-redirect